# Equivalents for genisoimage and qemu-img on Ubuntu

Tags: disk-utility, iso

How do I achieve the same result on OS X 10.9 as I do on Ubuntu with commands:

```
$ genisoimage -output init.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data
```

and

```
$ qemu-img convert -O raw disk.img disk.img.raw
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `mkisofs` instead of `genisoimage` - they are almost identical (mkisofs is actually newer and better maintained, while genisoimage is debian's old fork of it).

It comes with cdrtools, which you can install from brew:

```
brew install cdrtools
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ hdiutil makehybrid -o init.iso -hfs -joliet -iso -default-volume-name cidata config/
```

Where config/ contains meta-data and user-data.

```
$ brew install gemu
```